# Mostrar notas correspondientes al ID del contacto

Tags: laravel, eloquent

En la aplicación cada usuario puede crear contactos y esos contactos pueden tener muchas notas, obviamente si una nota es creada en un contacto entonces únicamente debe aparecer en las notas correspondientes a ese contacto. Es decir... cada contacto tiene sus notas personales.

El problema es que todas las notas que he creado se muestran en todos los contactos, no me muestra únicamente las que pertenecen a cada uno.

Me parece que el problema está en la línea donde pongo:

```
$notas = App\Nota::all();
```

porque estoy trayendo todas las notas, pero no se que otro método utilizar para mostrar solamente las notas creadas para ese contacto, aqui dejo el código de lo que tengo,

Controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}


public function contactos() {

     $usuarioEmail = auth()->user()->email;
     $contactos = App\Contacto::where('usuario', $usuarioEmail)->paginate(10);
    
     return view('contactos',compact('contactos'));
}

public function detalle($id) {

    $contact = App\Contacto::findOrFail($id);
    $notas = App\Nota::all();

    return view('contactos.detalle', compact('contact', 'notas'));
}

public function crear(Request $request) {
    // return $request->all();

    $request->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required',
        'apellidos' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'telefono' => 'required',
        'ubicacion' => 'required',
        'broker' => 'required'
    ]);

    $contactoNuevo = new App\Contacto;
    $contactoNuevo->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $contactoNuevo->apellidos = $request->apellidos;
    $contactoNuevo->email = $request->email;
    $contactoNuevo->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $contactoNuevo->ubicacion = $request->ubicacion;
    $contactoNuevo->broker = $request->broker;
    $contactoNuevo->usuario = auth()->user()->email;

    $contactoNuevo->save();

    

     return back()->with('mensaje', 'Contacto agregado');
}

public function editar($id) {

    $contact = App\Contacto::findOrFail($id);
    return view('contactos.editar', compact('contact'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id){

    $request->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required',
        'apellidos' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'telefono' => 'required',
        'ubicacion' => 'required',
        'broker' => 'required'
    ]);

    $contactUpdate = App\Contacto::findOrFail($id);
    $contactUpdate->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $contactUpdate->apellidos = $request->apellidos;
    $contactUpdate->email = $request->email;
    $contactUpdate->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $contactUpdate->ubicacion = $request->ubicacion;
    $contactUpdate->broker = $request->broker;

    $contactUpdate->save();

    return back()->with('mensaje', 'El contacto ha sido actualizado');

}

public function eliminar($id) {

    $contactoEliminar = App\Contacto::findOrFail($id);
    $contactoEliminar->delete();

    return back()->with('mensaje-eliminado', 'El contacto ha sido eliminado');
}

public function create(Request $request) {
    // return $request->all();

    $request->validate([
        'contenido' => 'required'
    ]);

    $notaNueva = new App\Nota;
    $notaNueva->contenido = $request->contenido;
    $notaNueva->contacto_id = $request->contacto_id;

    $notaNueva->save();

    

     return back()->with('mensaje', 'Nota agregada');
}


}
```

VISTA DEL DETALLE DE CADA CONTACTO, DONDE DEBEN APARECER LAS NOTAS CORRESPONDIENTES A CADA UNO (detalle.blade.php)

```
@foreach($notas as $nota)
<div id="accordion">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
  <h5 style="font-size:30px;" class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
         aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Nota
    </button>
  </h5>
</div>



<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">

  
  <div class="card-body">
    {{$nota->contenido}}
  </div>
  
</div>




</div>
```

YA TENGO CREADA LA LLAVE FORANEA Y LOS MODELOS ENLAZADOS

NOTA.php (MODELO)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nota extends Model
{
    public function contacto() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contacto::class);
    }
}
```

CONTACTO.php (MODELO)

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contacto extends Model
{
    public function notas() {
        return $this->hasMany(Nota::class);
    }
}
```

La iteración la hago con el siguiente foreach:

```
  @foreach($notas as $nota)
  <div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
  <h5 style="font-size:30px;" class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" 
aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Nota
    </button>
  </h5>
</div>



<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">

  
  <div class="card-body">
    {{ $nota->contenido }}
  </div>
  
</div>


     </div>


   </div>

@endforeach()
```

Si hago un return $notas; después de la consulta que me dijiste me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, Así quedó la consulta que me ayudaste pero adaptada a mis variables:

```
public function detalle($id) {

    $contact = App\Contacto::findOrFail($id);
    $notas = App\Contacto::with('notas')->findOrFail($id);
    
    return $notas;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener solo las notas de un contacto debes:

- Usar el modelo Contacto en la consulta
- Hacer una carga ambiciosa con *eager loading* de sus notas a través de la relación **`notas`**
- Para filtrar las notas de un solo contacto usa el método **`findOrFail`** y pásale el ID del contacto deseado

Así:

```
$consulta = Contacto::with('notas')->findOrFail($idContacto);
```

Para mostrar los datos del contacto es así directo indicando que propiedades deseas ver (**aquí no requieres un foreach**)

```
{{ $consulta->propiedadModeloContacto }}
```

Posterior para las notas como estarás obteniendo múltiples si necesitas iterar así

```
 @foreach($consulta->notas as $nota)
      {{ $nota->propiedadUnoNotas }}
      {{ $nota->propiedadDosNotas }}
 @endforeach
```

Tu variable consultas accede a la relación notas y a partir de ahí imprimes los datos

Comment: Ya lo coloqué como me dijiste y si me está trayendo los datos si pongo un return $notas; en formato JSON, pero lo intento enviar a una vista y me da el error: Trying to get property 'contenido' of non-object. Contenido es la variable donde estoy haciendo el foreach en la vista

Comment: listo, lo puse hasta el final de la pregunta

Comment: Ya quedó! muchas gracias por tu ayuda!